# How to get the name of recorder video from red5 server?

Tags: json, html, flash, local-storage, red5

I am using red5 server for video streaming/ recording. It works fine. Now I want to store name of recorded video some file or to json. Is it possible?  Video file is get stores in Red5\webapps\oflaDemo\streams directory. How to proceed? Your help will be appreciable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

https://github.com/Eltondcr/Red5RecordingAndListing

list in json and make records of streams.

Red5 versions: 1.0.1 >